# Embedded Jetty Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException

Tags: java, netbeans, embedded-jetty

I am attempting to embed Jetty 9.1.4.v20140401 into my application. I can get the code to compile, but I get this error when attempt to run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:107)
at com.example.WebService.main(WebService.java:82)
Java Result: 1
```

I am using Netbeans to compile the project, and I am not using Maven. Based on other searches I appear to be missing a jar when I attempt to run the code, but I included both the jetty-all and servlet-api jars in my run profile. What do I need to include to get this code to run correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exception when I was running jetty + jersey + atmosphere in a stand alone way.

These are links that could help:

- https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ludo/archive/2007/01/java_ee_5_apis.html
- http://helponjee.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/classformaterror-absent-code-attribute.html

I will write it down in case the links are fallen (it works for me to solve it)

**Root Cause:**
This is because of javaeeapi.jar present in your build path, for the transaction annotation

**Explanation:**
The Java EE API jar has been published via a Maven repository.
You can compile your code with this jar, but of course you cannnot run your application with it since it contains only the Java EE APIs and does not contain any method bodies. 
If you try to run, you would get this exception.

**Solution:**
Remove the javaeeapi.jar from the build path as it doesn't have proper class definition instead only class body

**Note:** In my case I removed that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```